# Unable to place a trailing stop loss order with ccxt

Tags: python, api, cryptocurrency, ccxt

I'm running an algorithm to predict prices and enter trades for me using the ccxt API in python. I wish to execute a trailing stop loss order and I enter such a long position like this:

```
exchange = ccxt.binance({
    'enableRateLimit': True,
    'apiKey': '*****',
    'secret': '*****'
})

exchange.load_markets()

exchange.create_order('MKR/USDT, 'TRAILING_STOP_MARKET', 'buy', exchange.fetch_balance()['USDT']['free']/exchange.fetch_ticker('MKR/USDT)['last'], None, params = {'callbackRate': 1})
```

but I get the following error:

> ccxt.base.errors.InvalidOrder: binance TRAILING_STOP_MARKET is not a valid order type in spot market MKR/USDT

I'm not sure why thought because I'm pretty sure binance supports trailing stop loss orders (it says so in its own API documentation).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Binance does not support the `TRAILING_STOP_MARKET` order type with spot markets (which is the default with CCXT):

- https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#new-order-trade

Binance only supports the `TRAILING_STOP_MARKET` order type with futures-markets:

- https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/futures/en/#new-order-trade

If you want to switch to the Binance futures API with CCXT you can do the following:

```
exchange = ccxt.binance({
    'enableRateLimit': True,
    'apiKey': '*****',
    'secret': '*****'
    'options': {
        'defaultType': 'future',  # or 'delivery' for COIN-M futures
    },
})

exchange.load_markets()

exchange.create_order('MKR/USDT, 'TRAILING_STOP_MARKET', 'buy', exchange.fetch_balance()['USDT']['free']/exchange.fetch_ticker('MKR/USDT)['last'], None, params = {'callbackRate': 1})
```

Answer (score 1):

Binance REST API doesn't support `TRAILING_STOP_MARKET`, see "Order types" in the [Enum definitions](https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md#enum-definitions).

If you want to simulate a trailing stop order, you'll need to subscribe to the [trade stream](https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/web-socket-streams.md#trade-streams) and keep recalculating your stop price. When the current market price reaches the stop price, submit a new order.